# What airlines offer or used to offer birthday cakes?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, dietary-restrictions

Inspired by [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94885/why-do-airlines-offer-more-varieties-of-special-request-meals-than-they-actually): two of the [IATA Meal Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_code#IATA_meal_codes), next to the usual vegetarian, bland, Kosher etc meals, are `CAKE` Birthday Cake and `CLML` Celebration Cake Meal.

**On which airlines can or could I actually eat cake?**  The Wiki page above credits `CAKE` to Scandinavian Airlines, but as a former SAS frequent flyer, I've never heard of much less seen this supposed perk.

For avoidance of doubt, this is specifically about being able to preorder a "cake meal", having a slice included as a part of your regular meal doesn't cut it.

Comment: It seems SAS did it once upon a time but [discontinued it quite some time ago](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/sas-eurobonus/1264036-birthday-cake.html)

Comment: Virgin America certainly did it ([source](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g34515-i19-k864536-Birthday_Cake_on_Virgin_Flight-Orlando_Florida.html) ) but the very airline is gone. Virgin Atlantic too [source](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/3479059/celebrate-onboard-virgin-atlantic), [source](https://v-flyer.com/viewtopic.php?p=431535#p431535) not sure what's going on now.

Comment: Check the last sentence, I also know that they provide birthday cakes but it's not advertised: https://www.saudia.com/before-flying/special-assistance/special-meals

Comment: I've flown 100s+ of times and never seen a birthday cake. I might also not have noticed if it happens somewhere out of of my sight without drawing a lot of attention to it

Comment: @Hilmar: so did I, all over the world. I did not even know that this was an option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Several airlines offer birthday cakes, or at least did before the pandemic (many catering options and special meals were discontinued during COVID).

Turkish Airlines offered a "[celebration cake](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/miles-and-smiles/program-content/celebration-cake/)," though the program is currently suspended. When they were being offered, they'd provide free cake for birthdays and wedding anniversaries. You can see [some pictures](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/turkish-airlines-miles-smiles/1453423-what-s-celebration-cake-2.html) of those who received it.

[This 2018 article](https://www.cntraveler.com/story/how-to-get-an-in-flight-cake-delivery) lists other airlines that have offered birthday cakes: "Korean Air, Turkish Airlines, SpiceJet, Swiss, Qatar Airways, and Cathay Pacific are just a few airlines that will bake a cake or special dessert for onboard enjoyment." Some other airlines may offer a special treat to top-tier frequent flyers reaching certain milestones. It looks like Indian carriers GoAir, SpiceJet, and Vistara [have offered cakes](https://aviationscoop.com/goair-vistara-and-spicejet-birthday-cakes-offer/10761/), and IndiGo used to.

Some airlines charge for the service: [Hong Kong Airlines has several cake and champagne options](https://www.hkairlines.com/en_HK/fly-with-us/inflight-services/cakechampagne), and [Cathay Pacific had a charge as well](https://onemileatatime.com/cathay-pacific-birthday-cake/). [Emirates used to](https://viewfromthewing.com/loved-one-flying-order-an-inflight-birthday-cake-on-four-major-airlines/) before the pandemic. And some airlines (apparently [including Singapore](https://www.executivetraveller.com/how-airlines-can-help-you-celebrate-special-occasions)) might be able to offer one but don't advertise it as an option. Cakes may only be available on certain routes.

The pandemic makes an answer with a complete list of airlines not really practical, since it seems many airlines that previously had cakes aren't doing them right now. But a search for "[airline name] birthday cake" should provide any relevant information.

Comment: On a more technical note, did any of these airlines actually let you choose CAKE/CLML while booking, right next to normal and vegetarian food? The Turkish Airlines cake looks like something you request by email.

Answer (score 2):

In [this list](http://www.amadeus.com/msite/ancillaryservices-necse/en/meals.html) from Amadeus, a company that sells travel booking software, I can see two cake listings:

- Air Austral - Birthday cake (BDML)
- Niki (no longer exists) - Niki special cake (HPML)

Scandinavian is listed there but with no cake listing. I couldn't find any cake listings on other systems either. I don't have the money to travel with Air Austral right now so I can't confirm if the option to book a cake exists, but if you were booking with a travel agent they would theoretically put a request in a SPML (special meal) which is a free text field regardless of airline.

Also according to [this forum post](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/sas-eurobonus/1264036-birthday-cake.html) from 2011, SAS used to have a cake option.

Comment: Air Austral also appears to have a Champagne meal `CPML` and a Caviar meal `CVML`, so even if they have no cake, I'd be pretty happy with those instead!