# How do I make sure I'm not awakened during in-flight food service?

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, in-flight-services, cabin-crew

Inspired by [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99465/can-i-miss-the-in-flight-food), I was wondering what the best way is to *make sure* I miss the in-flight food. The reasons are the following:

- The flight is 6-7 hours, starting slightly before midnight. This means it departs after I usually go to bed, and arrive earlier than I usually wake up.
- It is recommended to avoid the in-flight food from this particular airport, in order to avoid stomach problems.

Hence, my plan is to have dinner shortly before leaving and sleep during the whole flight. How do I ensure that neither the cabin crew nor other passengers wake me up?

The answer by Nean Der Thal on the linked question provides some helpful pointers, but I've never seen any DND stickers on the flights I've been on.

Comment: Do they even serve dinner on your flight.  The vast majority of long haul flights I have been on that leave near midnight do not serve a hot meal at the start, just a breakfast snack before landing.

Comment: @Tom Yes, they do. I flew from this airport a couple of weeks ago (around midnight) and they served dinner. I flew to this airport this week (also around midnight) and dinner was served that time as well.

Comment: Hand write a sign that says No Food Thanks (in the appropriate language) and tape it to your head rest before you try to sleep.

Comment: If it's just a matter of not trusting that the food is safe to eat, **just saying "no thanks" is allowed**.

Comment: I've never had crew wake me up for a meal or snack if I slept through it. What airline does that?

Comment: @ThePhoton: Apparently, whichever airline [this user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/99502/1362) works for...

Comment: @Dorothy thanks for the edit, the new title better reflects what I'm after. I want to avoid being disturbed, and while that mainly happens when meals are served, there could be other reasons as well.

Comment: @HenricF sure; you could tweak it even more, saying 'not disturbed at all'... and for that, what works for many is to wear an eye mask, headphones, and wrap in the blanket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inform the air hostess in advance that you would not like to be disturbed for the food. They note down your seat number and whosoever hostess would be serving your aisle, would know not to wake you up for food or drinks.

Few flights do offer the DND stickers that you can stick to your seat too to convey the message.