# Asking for a second helping of a meal only if available?

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, in-flight-services

Sometimes when I'm on a plane, the in-flight meals are really quite delicious and I might want to try the *other* set that I did not choose (or have more of the same!). I have asked if there was extra meal kits left over a couple of times, much later when it was time for a snack ... and was informed they were all out.

Now, it seems based on [Can I accidentally miss the in-flight food?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/99465/3640) that perhaps this isn't just a matter of demand, but regulations forcing the crew to dispose of heated food.

If I want to convey that I might like to try another course but without coming across as a selfish pig, and I only want it after everyone else is served, not disturbing crew too much - how would I go about asking for it?

Comment: Wow, it's certainly rare to hear airplane food described as "really quite delicious".

Comment: @GregHewgill Its not always, but I have been pleasantly surprised by Indian meals en route to India on Emirates or Singapore (unfortunately, Jet-based Etihad service is not in this category :( )

Comment: Wish I could give this more than +1 - I'm a greedy pig, but don't want to come across as a selfish one!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking politely, just be sure to wait until *after* the first service is complete.

Comment: @GregHewgill Not at all. In Asia the airline food is usually very good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just ask for it nicely and politely. *"Hi, thanks for the food, it's really yummy. If you have to happen some left over and it's not too much trouble, I would appreciate trying the pasta too."*

They may say yes, they may say no. There is quite a bit of variability in "friendliness" of the crew.

Comment: The key part missing from this answer is *when*. Is it directly after they've served you? Is it possible to tell when they've finished serving others and ask then? Do you wait until they're clearing trays, or is it too late by then? Or should I ask *before* they serve food?

Comment: Always ask after the crew have done the main service. They're unlikely to say yes while they're still serving, because cabin crew hate telling a passenger their choice of 'chicken/beef' is unavailable. Afterwards, and - as always - highly dependent on the crew, the don't mind slinging another meal to you: although note they'll want you to be discrete about it. Crew also hate 'I saw him get an xyz, now I want one'. They're desperate to finish the meal service and start relaxing!

Answer (score 5):

I went with Srilankan airlines. After everyone has been served and I finished my meal, I quietly went to the back of the plane, politely got an air hostess's attention and said.

> Do you happen to have any extra meal packets available? Any kind is
> OK, as I am still hungry.

The air-hostess happily provided one then and there.